# Laravel Built in Server not persisting session and causes TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, session, csrf

I've been using Laravel  for a while, have gone through a few projects, and never experienced this:

Suddenly my application was having TokenMismatchException and creating new sessions between requests.

After hours of searching for a solution, and tried every session driver i tried to use XAMPP instead of Laravel's built-in server.

> php artisan serve    /   http://localhost:8000

with XAMPP:

> http://localhost/myproject/public

And then the CSRF persisted as well as the sessions, and every session driver started to work fine once again.

Strangest thing is, i tried to use php artisan serve again and the problem went away.

I thought i should stick to php artisan serve, but now i'm starting to guess.

Does anyone have a clue about this strange behavior? so we can save people from this headache. Thanks in advance

Comment: sometimes the TokenMismatchException is due to not being logged out or a refresh and when you go back to the site etc its kept the old session and compares to the new instance and thus not matching, try to clear browser cache etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not that case. I've already studied that scenario and read the CSRF background. In this case the CSRF Token and Session were not persisting, They were being set again on every request.

Comment: if using XAMPP its best to set up a host file to point to the public folder so you can use say mysite.dev, acessing it like http://localhost/myproject/public, will load the main page but will probably fail if linking else where.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks. But i don't think that answers the question. I have that config in my production server, without having to add a host file. Just pointing the root directory of my domain to public_html/public. 

What i'm not getting here is the session's unpersistence through php artisan serve. Does it have something to do with laravel's built in server? i'm not getting this error on my production server or through XAMPP.

Comment: sorry, i don't use the php server/ server as use a vm like homestead or local ubuntu sever, sorry cannto help further

Comment: Thanks, you did help. Next time i'll use Homestead. Let us see if someone comes up with an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary workaround always open your browser in Incognito or Private mode when using php artisan serve

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This should really be a comment on the OP's question, rather than an Answer. When you have 50 or more rep points you'll be able to comment. In the meantime, please read [answer] for tips on answering questions.

Comment: For me it doesn't work with incognito, I get a new session with each page view (although sessions are stored in database)